# Android taking picture with camera and save to sqlite causes java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't compress a recycled bitmap

Tags: android, sqlite, bitmap, camera

Android app trying to save an image to the sqlite database using content resolver after taking a photo with the camera.

However no matter what I do I still get variations of "Can't compress a recycled bitmap"

I have looked at numerous posts on stackoverflow but none of them address my issue. I can't seem to find the code where my bitmap is recycled causing the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't compress a recycled bitmap
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkRecycled(Bitmap.java:394)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.java:1077)
    at com.wernerraubenheimer.ujcp.fragments.UserInputFragment.getBytes(UserInputFragment.java:269)
    at com.wernerraubenheimer.ujcp.fragments.UserInputFragment.saveImage(UserInputFragment.java:248)
    at com.wernerraubenheimer.ujcp.fragments.UserInputFragment.onActivityResult(UserInputFragment.java:241)
```

My code:

```
private void takePhotoFromCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED) {
        return;
    }
    if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri contentURI = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), contentURI);
                saveImage(bitmap);
                CircleTransform circleTransform = new CircleTransform();
                avatarView.setImageBitmap(circleTransform.transform(bitmap));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    } else if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        CircleTransform circleTransform = new CircleTransform();
        avatarView.setImageBitmap(circleTransform.transform(thumbnail));
        saveImage(thumbnail);
    }
}

public void saveImage(Bitmap myBitmap) {

    ContentValues userValues = new ContentValues();
    userValues.put(ProgrammeCourseContract.LearnersEntry.COLUMN_AVATAR, getBytes(myBitmap));

    if(!HAS_AVATAR) {
        userValues.put(ProgrammeCourseContract.LearnersEntry._ID, 1); // Only one user for now, future may include more
        getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(
                ProgrammeCourseContract.LearnersEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                userValues);

    } else { //there is already an avatar image, save the new one
        getActivity().getContentResolver().update(
                ProgrammeCourseContract.LearnersEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                userValues,
                ProgrammeCourseContract.LearnersEntry._ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{"1"});
    }
    onAvatarUpdateListener.onAvatarUpdate();
}

// convert from bitmap to byte array
public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}

// convert from byte array to bitmap
public static Bitmap getImage(byte[] image) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
}
```

Comment: `CircleTransform` is likely recycling the `Bitmap` you pass it. You need to keep a reference to the `Bitmap` returned from `circleTransform.transform()`, and pass that to your `saveImage()` method. For example: `Bitmap newBmp = circleTransform.transform(thumbnail);`, `avatarView.setImageBitmap(newBmp);`, `saveImage(newBmp);`. Unless you don't want to save the transformed `Bitmap`, in which case, save it first, before you pass it to `CircleTransform`.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. Moved saveImage(thumbnail) to before the Circle transform and now it saves correctly. I actually did that when I saved an image from selecting from the gallery. Didn't realize it would make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

As per Mike M, moved saveImage(thumbnail) to before CircleTransform:

```
else if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            saveImage(thumbnail);
            CircleTransform circleTransform = new CircleTransform();
            avatarView.setImageBitmap(circleTransform.transform(thumbnail));
        }
```